# Manejo de Versiones en PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php7, php5

Estuve desarrollando una vista con **PHP 7 Y SQL SERVER 2012**, en donde el usuario filtra los datos en base a una fecha inicial , un rango de fechas , por beneficiario, entre otros.

Todas las consultas y la vista funciona sin ningún problema de forma **local**.

Al trasladar la carpeta directo al servidor en productivo, tuve problemas con las **versiones en php**, realicé el cambio respectivo de las versiones y al momento de realizar las pruebas , algunas de las consultas , **específicamente las que trabajan con las fechas** , no me están trayendo la data.

Cabe destacar que ya me aseguré de **copiar y pegar los códigos correctamente**.

¿Cuál sería el problema?

````
    if($v1 == 1 && $v2 != null && $v3 != null && $v4 != null)
    {

    echo("
                        <thead>
                            <th>Teléfono</th>
                            <th>Cédula</th>
                            <th>Beneficiario</th>
                            <th>Tarjeta</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Fecha de Consulta</th>
                        </thead>
        ");
        $consulta = "
                    declare @Fecha_ini  datetime 
                    declare @Fecha_fin datetime 

                    set @Fecha_ini = '$v2'
                    set @Fecha_fin = '$v3'

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono,
                                CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,2),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,3,3),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,6,6)) AS Cedula,
                                CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre,
                                NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta,
                                tarjetas.cliente as Cliente,
                                Producto.nombre as Producto,
                                Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id =   Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '8'  and replace(cedula,'.','') = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)

                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.FechaConsulta asc) T

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-   ',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,1),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,3,3),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,5,5)) AS   Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido)  AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id =   Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '7'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.FechaConsulta asc) T1

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,3),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,4,6)) AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido)      AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha 
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id =       Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '6'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.FechaConsulta asc) T2 

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,2),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,3,5)) AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto
                            where LEN(Cedula) = '5'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.FechaConsulta asc) T3

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,1),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,2,4)) AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto
                            where LEN(Cedula) = '4'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.FechaConsulta asc) T4

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,Cedula AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '3'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.FechaConsulta asc) T5

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS NumeroTelefono
                                ,Cedula AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '2'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by FechaConsulta asc) T6

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,Cedula AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto
                            where LEN(Cedula) = '1'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  = $v4 and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.FechaConsulta asc) T7 

                            ";
    $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta);
    $i = 0;
    $NumeroFilas = sqlsrv_has_rows($ejecutar);

    if($NumeroFilas == 0)
    {
        echo('<script> alert("No existen registros con los datos solicitados"); window.history.back();</script>');
    }

    else
    {
        while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar))
        {

            $NumeroTelefono = $fila['NumeroTelefono'];
            $Cedula = $fila['Cedula'];
            $Nombre = $fila['Nombre'];
            $NumeroTarjeta = $fila['Tarjeta'];
            $Cliente = $fila['Cliente'];
            $Producto   = $fila['Producto'];
            $FechaConsulta = $fila['Fecha'];
            $i++;

            echo("<tbody>
                    <td>$NumeroTelefono</td>
                    <td>$Cedula</td>
                    <td>$Nombre</td>
                    <td>$NumeroTarjeta</td>
                    <td>$Cliente</td>
                    <td>$Producto</td>
                    <td>$FechaConsulta</td>
                </tbody>
                "
                );

        }
    }```
````

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para conversaciones extendidas. Los comentarios se eliminaron pero [la conversación continuó en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103911/discussion-between-invictus-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré resolver el problema, a continuación la solución a mi caso utilizaré las mismas variables planteadas:

**1.** Primero verifiqué como se está captando **las fechas (sus formatos)** con un `var_dump($v2)`:

`$v2 = "27/09/2019"`

**2.** Las variables que manejaban **fechas las dividí en 3 cadenas mas pequeñas , utilizando la función/método de php llamado** `substr()` **que divide una cadena,en cadenas mas pequeñas:**

`$v5 = substr($v2,-4);
$v6 = substr($v2,3,-5);
$v7 = substr($v2,0,-8);`

Estas tres variables obtienen **día ,mes y año** y lo que hice fue ordenarlos en esta forma **añomesdia , sin separarlas con ningún caracter.**

**3.** A mis variables tipo `DateTime` dentro de mi consulta les pase estas tres variables:

`declare @Fecha_ini datetime 
set @Fecha_ini = '$v5$v6$v7'`

Ya de esta forma la fecha ingresa a la consulta con este formato : `'20190927'`, investigué que esta forma de presentar los datos cuando sean del tipo `Date/DateTime` en **SQL SERVER** es la ideal , ya que, es un **Estandar** y va a ignorar los problemas que se te puedan presentar con respecto a **la zona horaria de la Máquina Local/Servidor configuradas.**

**4.** Por último, **optimicé las consultas** y en la variable que guarda los resultados de las **Fechas** le coloqué la función/método de php llamado `date_format()`:

`$FechaConsulta = date_format($fila['FechaConsulta'],'d/m/Y');`